# mvn - inject log4j.properties into maven plugin

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I have two projects:

- I have made a Maven MOJO *company:generation-plugin* which generates some code. The Maven phase is *generate-sources*.
- In a client project, I use the plugin as following:

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>company</groupId>
          <artifactId>generation-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>generate</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  ```

Both the generation project and the client project have a *log4j.properties* in *src/main/resources*.

The problem is that during the generation of the sources in the client project, the *log4j.properties* of the generation project is used.

Is it possible to inject the *log4j.properties* of the client project into the generation project, or in other words, replace *log4j.properties* of the generation project with *log4j.properties* of the client project?

**update**

When *log4j.properties* of the generation project is moved to *src/test/resources* or simply deleted, the client project gets the following warning during building:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Somehow, I must be able to tell the generation project to use the *log4.properties* from the client project.

Comment: One possible solution would be not to have a log4j.properties inside src/main/resources of your plugin. Why do you really need it inside src/main/resources? If it's for testing purposes, it should be inside src/test/resources

Comment: @Tunaki I'll update my question.

Comment: It seems you are not using the [standard Mojo way](https://maven.apache.org/developers/mojo-api-specification.html) to log messages. Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @Tunaki I will check that out. It is not the MOJO itself who is logging, it is the library FreeMarker who is logging. The plugin calls FreeMarker functionality.

Comment: It does not make sense that your plugin would pick up the local src/main/resources into its classpath and thus find log4j.properties. Do you do anything 'funny' with log4j initialization, like set a system property to 'src/main/resource/log4j.properties'? you should not.

Comment: @bmargulies No, no system property is set. I rely only on Maven here. I understand the plugin cannot pick up the local log4j.properties, how is there a way to inject it? I want to alter how the plugin behaves with respect to logging.

Comment: set MAVEN_OPTS="-Dlog4j.debug" and see if it sheds any light.v Maybe move this to the maven user's mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't enough information here to solve the problem, but the question implicitly asks for some information about how Maven and log4j works.

1. Maven creates a separate class loader for each plugin as it executes. That plugin contains the declared dependencies (runtime+compile) *of the plugin itself*. The plugin class loader does *not* incorporate the project's target/classes; though some plugins which need to examine classes (for code modification) go to extra trouble to poke around in there.
2. Log4j looks for log4j.properties in some class loader. It is possible that log4j is not using the right class loader, dependending on the versions of log4j and Maven; you could try setting the thread context class loader to the class loader that loaded your mojo and see what happens.
3. In theory, you could bridge log4j to the Maven mojo log; I can't find an example of this lying about, so you might need to code it up from the log4j doc yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I will deep into it and let you know!